# JSF2 - How to create a link containing parameters and anchor?

Tags: jsf-2, hyperlink, anchor

I want to produce a link looking like this:

```
http://domain.com/page.jsf?test=12#top
```

I tried using `<h:outputLink>` :

```
<h:outputLink value="/page.jsf#top">
    <f:param name="test" value="12" />
    My link
</h:outputLink>
```

But it failed and produced the link `http://domain.com/page.jsf#top?test=12`, which is wrong.

Is there a way to do this using JSF, or do I have to create this kind of links "manually"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since JSF 2.0 there is an [`<h:link>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) component that takes a JSF navigation case outcome through its `outcome` attribute, thus making it a perfect candidate for navigation within a JSF-based application. The component you used, `<h:outputLink>` is best used for navigation to the external world. You can of course use it to handle JSF navigation but it will feel plain clumsy.

If you decide to switch to `<h:link>` you can make use of its `fragment` attribute to attach your anchor (always look at the documentation - linked above):

> The identifier of the page fragment which should be brought into focus when the target page is rendered. The value of this attribute is appended to the end of target URL following a hash (#) mark. This notation is part of the standard URL syntax.

All in all, your link should come as:

```
<h:link value="My link" outcome="/page" fragment="top">
    <f:param name="test" value="12" />
</h:link>
```

It will produce the HTML that you desire.

### Further point of reference:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Comment: Damn, I swear I tried the `<h:link>`'s **fragment** attribute and it didn't work. I must have messed up my test somewhere... Thanks, I'd never had tried it again if it weren't for your advice!